# Slide up on hover on the image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a slide up effect while hovering on the div.

```css
.intro-page__img {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border: solid 1px #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #eee;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.intro-page__link:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.theme_view{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.theme_view .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  background: url(data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuNUmK/OAAAAATSURBVBhXY2RgYNgHxGAAYuwDAA78AjwwRoQYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat scroll transparent\9;
  z-index:9999;
  color:black;
  height:65px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
}
.theme_view:hover .overlay{
  display:block;
  margin-top:-200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="theme_view">
              <img class="img-responsive intro-page__img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="">
              <div class="overlay">
                   <button class="btn btn-dark custom_button_width margin_top_15">Preview</button>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It would be great if it is done by using only CSS. I want to slide up the **Preview** Button div when i hover on the image.

Thank You.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 100% width and -60% for hiding the preview button.(If you are using 100% width then slide will be responsive and slide up button properly works)

```css
  .intro-page__link:hover {
  color: #666;
  }
  .theme_view{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
  .theme_view .overlay {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom: -60%;
  transition: all .35s;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAYAAABytg0kAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAgY0hSTQAAeiYAAICEAAD6AAAAgOgAAHUwAADqYAAAOpgAABdwnLpRPAAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAUGFpbnQuTkVUIHYzLjUuNUmK/OAAAAATSURBVBhXY2RgYNgHxGAAYuwDAA78AjwwRoQYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat scroll transparent\9;
  z-index:9999;
  color:black;
  height:65px;
  border:1px solid #eee;
  }
  .theme_view:hover .overlay{
  bottom:0;
  }
  .btn { margin-top: 12px;}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  
  <div class="theme_view">
  <img class="img-responsive intro-page__img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" alt="">
  <div class="overlay">
  <button class="btn btn-dark custom_button_width">Preview</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple transform: translateY() on the div should do it for you.
I normally use either px or % with the translate-property, like this: 
transform: translateY(-10%);

The transition-property is not necessary, but I'd recommend it, to make the animation smoother. You have to play around with the speed of the transition, but generally speaking 0.1s - 0.4s (100-400 miliseconds) are the recommended speeds for animations on webpages.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example but you must integrate this in your own code, so you can learn too:P

```css
 .hide {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
 h1:hover + .hide {
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
    max-height: 1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">Show Test</a></h1>
<p class="hide">I'm a barbie girl in a barbie world. All is plastic, its fantastic!</p>
```

Comment: If you want, i can edit it and make it compatible to your code.